# Hibernate+JPA+guice entity not persisted into database

Tags: java, entity-framework, hibernate, jpa, guice

I'm now using hibernate, JPA and guice for persistence. When I try to create an entity on html page, it is not throwing any error, but the data cannot be found in the database. Actually the entity was created, but I have no idea where it was saved. Because when I try to create an entity with the same primary key, it would jump into entityexistsexception.

service.java

```
package com.edit.foo.service;

import com.edit.common.domain.Party;
import com.edit.foo.persistence.PartyStore;
import com.google.inject.persist.Transactional;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import java.util.List;

@Singleton
public class PartyService {

private final PartyStore store;

@Inject
public PartyService (PartyStore store) {
    this.store = store;
}

@Transactional
public Party findById(String key) {
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(key))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("");
    return store.findById(key);
}

@Transactional
public List<Party> search(String filter) {
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(filter))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("");
    return store.findAllWithNameContaining(filter);
}

@Transactional
public Party create(Party party) {
    return store.create(party);
}

@Transactional
public Party update(Party party) {
    return store.update(party);
}
}
```

interface

```
package com.edit.foo.persistence;

import com.google.inject.persist.Transactional;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;
import java.util.List;

public abstract class HibernatePersistentStore<E> implements PersistentStore<E> {
private final Class<E> clazz;

@Inject
protected EntityManager entityManager;

protected HibernatePersistentStore(Class<E> clazz) {
    this.clazz = clazz;
}

@Override
public E findById(String id) {
    return entityManager.find(clazz, id);
}

@Transactional
@Override
public List<E> findAll(Specification<E> filter) {
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<E> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(clazz);
    Root<E> root = criteriaQuery.from(clazz);

    criteriaQuery.select(root).where(
            filter.toPredicate(root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder)
    );

    return entityManager
            .createQuery(criteriaQuery)
            .getResultList();
}

@Transactional
@Override
public E create(E entity) {
    entityManager.persist(entity);
    return entity;
}

@Transactional
@Override
public E update(E entity) {
    return entityManager.merge(entity);
}
}
```

What could possibly be the reason for this?

Comment: What is 'PartyStore'? I am not sure here but try removing @Transactional from the Interface and play around with flush() to see why you are not commiting the transaction automatically.